# Create a custom Vector Source for OpenLayers for referenced tiles

Tags: openlayers

I have a custom vector storage, using [Flatbuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/) (if you’re not familiar: similar to pbf). It would take me a bit longer to describe the format in details, though it is different to other vector formats like mvt in that it is independent of a projection: Where other vector formats have to adhere to a certain projection and have to alter geometries (e.g. cut along tile bounds which is then also depending on the projection / tile bounds), my format always returns complete geometries.

This works already in a product available for iOS and Android. Though the culprit is that this format requires an extra step when fetching the tiles: Each tile may have referenced tiles, which also need to be loaded. This is because I use full geometries, and therefore tiles where geometries laying in one tile and overlapping other(s) have to be loaded as well.

I should I implement such behaviour in OpenLayers, loading depending tiles and also showing geometries of referenced tiles which might nit be in the current view (as per commonly implemented vector / raster sources), but containing overlapping geometries which need to be shown?